# subtracting two columns in python on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to subtract the a value of column new_azi and column angle in the azimuth dataframe on condition that the first is >= the second so what I did

```
if azimuth['new_azi'] >= azimuth['angle']:
    azimuth['new_azi'] = azimuth['new_azi'] - 360
```

but this error occurs

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: So, `azimuth` is a pandas DataFrame??

Comment: I like to use np.where() `azimuth['new_azi'] = np.where((azimuth['new_azi'] >= azimuth['angle']), azimuth['new_azi'] - 360, azimuth['new_azi'])`